# How to enable android studio new logcat in Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Canary 6?

Tags: android, logcat, android-studio-3.1, android-studio-dolphin

`In Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Canary 6` version Android studio updated with new [logcat](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/03/android-studio-dolphin-canary-6-now.html), by default not getting enabled(after the updated to Dolphin), How to enable that?

[image: logcatnew]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Follow this path

**File -> Settings -> Experimental or you can search Logcat->** enable the **Enable new Logcat tool window** -> Apply and click ok,

> Restart the IDE to Apply the Changes.

[image: img1]

Comment: how to show error logs only?

Comment: you can use - level:Error , better if want to know, how to use other things, let's watch this video - https://youtu.be/AY4y0pr-O_c

Answer (score 1):

Those who come here to know how to filter (see only errors etc.)

[image]

Google info link:
[How to use new logcat](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/03/android-studio-dolphin-canary-6-now.html)

**If link not working check this**:
[image: How to]

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/logcat-in-dolphin-version-1ae7f5f687f4